# Approximation Ratios

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I've got a question about how best to classify the performance of an approximate algorithm. I'm trying to find the 'correct' value of a graph problem instance whose cost function has an objective function and a penalty function. I've configured my method such that the optimum solution of the problem has the highest value, fulfilling the objective criterion adds to the cost function value, and the penalty subtracts from it. This means that some poor solutions have negative values.

Typically the performance of an approximate algorithm is measured as:

found_cost_function_value / best_possible_solution   = r .

I'm a little confused where to set my baseline of 0 however. Should I translate my objective values such  that they are all positive, and so add the | most_negative_solution_cost_function_value| to all my cost function values and the best_possible_solution? Or is it best practise to calculate r as found ?

EDIT: This is an optimisation problem. Each instance can be assigned an objective value. In my setup I've got a bit of an issue in that I found it best for the execution of the algorithm to have the penalty terms much larger than my reward terms and so I have a distribution of solutions with a small head of positive terms and a large tail of grossly negative solutions which skew things if I force everyting to be between 0 <r <1.

Comment: A few things aren't clear to me: (1) Is this an optimisation problem? For such a problem, any instance that satisfies some constraints C can be assigned a score according to an objective function (which may incorporate penalties as terms or factors), and the goal is to find an instance that satisfies constraints C and minimises (or maximises) this function.

Comment: This is a known issue with approximation ratios. I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I've edited the question but 1) yes. The problem is that different elements of my objective function tug in different ways.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat do you know of any authoritative articles that discuss it ? Or places to look ? Thanks

Comment: https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/

Comment: Thanks. One option you have is to push the objective function values through some monotone function that will make everything positive (e.g., exp()) before computing the ratio, although you may wind up with very large ratios, and if you take logs of them to "get back to sensible numbers" then you're just doing the same thing as computing best_possible_solution - found_cost_function_value. Maybe that difference is actually a better measure than the ratio?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat ah if only I'd seen this a good while ago !

Comment: @j_random_hacker that's a good idea actually. I suppose my ultimate question is whether there is a standard practise and there doesn't seem to be as David  points out.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Actually I'm not sure how valid this would be comparing across different problem instances. Hmm this is a tricky one!

Comment: Maybe   (exact_function_value - found_function_value )/ exact_function_value for each case ?

Comment: Agreed, I think the plain subtraction might tend to make larger problem instances artificially appear to be approximated worse (if both the best_possible_solution and found_cost_function_value go up by some factor, you would probably expect the difference between them to go by a similar factor). Tricky!